# Jerk in android animation when expanding a view

Tags: android, performance

I have been developing one application where I expand a view with property animation(Using nine old androids lib). And on animation end call back I set grid view's adapter. If I remove the set adapter part animation works fine. But if I add it at the end of animation I'm getting a jerk. Why it happens so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jerkiness is caused by setting the adapter (as you have guessed). Setting an adapter is not an easy task and since you're presumably doing it on the UI thread jerkiness is your result.

You can move the setting of the adapter to another thread which will allow the animation to continue smoothly while the setting of the adapter occurs asynchronously. See [Making ListView Scrolling Smooth | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) for more information on moving heavy tasks to another thread so that your main thread can focus on drawing the UI.

Comment: Thank you very much. Will try to implement it as you suggested.

Comment: As you suggested I tried to load the images in thread. But still jerkiness exists. Setting adapter in the animation end call back should not effect the animation right?. And when animation end call back is called, animation is complete or still there is fraction of time remaining for it's completion?